# Attempted Proof Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am new to the site and wanted to ask a question on an attempted proof of the Fundamental Th. of Algebra.

I tried to proove it as an exercise using only Euclidean Division in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{K[x]}$ ( where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field and came up with this proof) and other things known ( definition of root, definition of degree etc). Here is my proof:

Hp:
 If $\delta f(x) \geq 1$ where $f(x) \in \mathbb C[x]$ then $f(x)$ has atleast one root in $\mathbb{C}$

(Note, $\delta$ indicates degree of the polnomial)

Proof:

Let's suppose by reductio ad absurdum that there is such a polynomial $f(x)$ where $\delta f(x) \geq 1$ and it has no roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

Suppose that $\delta f(x) = 1$ which $=>$ $f(x) = 1 + ax$ (where $a \in \mathbb{C}$), therefore root is $-1/a$.

Let's assume therefore that $\delta f(x) > 1$.

By Euclidean division we have that $f(x) = q(x)g(x) +r(x)$,
Where $g(x)$ is an arbitrary ploynomial in $\mathbb{C[x]}$ that has atleast one root and where $\delta g(x) < \delta f(x)$

(Or in other words $\alpha$ is a root).

$f(x) = q(x)g(x) + r(x)$ where $\delta r(x) < \delta g(x)$ or  $\delta r(x) = 0$ (Here I am using Euclidean Division)

$f(x) - r(x) = q(x)g(x)$

Now calculate $f(x)$ in $\alpha$, if $f(\alpha) = r(\alpha) = 0$ then hp.

Otherwise $f(\alpha)\neq0$ then introduce polynomial $f'(x) = f(x) - f(\alpha)$, hence $f(x) = f'(x) + f(\alpha)$

This is an absurdity because we supposed that $f(x)$ didn't have roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

Q.E.D. I think. Is there an error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I find this hard to follow.

Comment: This argument works for *any* field, so there *has* to be a mistake.  Try to carry it out explicitly for $X^2+1$ in $\mathbb R$. You are not specifying, for example, by *which* polynomial you divide $f$.

Comment: Maybe rather than saying you have a question but then never asking one, you should say at the top that you are asking for a verification or refutation of your attempted proof.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I have adjusted the question accordingly. To Pedro Tamaroff, doesn't that imply that $\sqrt{-1}$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ which is incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect; the key error is the last step.  You started by assuming $f$ had no root, and eventually concluded that the polynomial $f'(x)=f(x)-f(\alpha)$ has a root.  This is no contradiction, because $f'$ is a different polynomial from $f$.  To get a contradiction, you would need to prove $f$ itself has a root.

(Note that in fact all your work leading up to this with $g(x)$, which is very hard to follow because you never actually clearly defined $g(x)$ or $\alpha$, is totally irrelevant.  If your last step worked, you could have just said "pick any $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, and then $f'(x)=f(x)-f(\alpha)$ has a root, contradiction".)

More broadly, as Pedro Tamaroff commented, this proof has no hope of working because you never used anything special about $\mathbb{C}$.  So if your proof worked, it would work for any field at all, but over fields different from $\mathbb{C}$ there are non-constant polynomials with no roots, so the result is not true.

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't stating that $f(x) = f'(x) + f(\alpha)$ prove that there is a root? My basic idea was to translate the polynomial function on the $\mathbb{C}$ plane in order for it to have a root (which is why I used Euclidean division, in order to find this constant).

Comment: What root are you claiming that $f$ has?

Comment: Ok I think I understand the problem. Let's take $x^2 +1$ as an example, then assume that there is such $q(x), r(x)$ so x^2+1 = $g(x)q(x) + r(x)$ where all said polynomials are those of my original question (regarding the roots for $g(x)$ etc). I then calculate this in $\alpha$ obtaining that $\alpha^2 + 1 = c$ where $c = r(\alpha)$. Now $\alpha^2 + 1 - c = 0$ meaning that there is somewhere where the function is null. We then take the inverse of the polynomial $\alpha^2 + 1 - c$ (which exists because we are in a ring) and find that it has a root, thus a contradiction.
Thanks for your patience

Comment: And I see your point. When taking the inverse of the polynomial it is here that I use the fact that we are working in $\mathbb{C[x]}$, as I can't do the same in $\mathbb{R[x]}$ (once again because of $\sqrt{-1}$).

Comment: That still doesn't sound right to me.  What do you mean by "take the inverse", and how are you getting a root of $f$ from that?